# angular material2 advance usage

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have been googling and trying to find Is there a way/document in angular material 2 ways to set

1. Background color of div
2. color of div
3. padding, margin
4. different layouts planned (even in Q4 I didn't see any)

and advance stuff ?

Comment: Use scss, create new classes and sets the desired properties to the @angular/material variables.

Comment: Maybe check out this document https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

Comment: @Ploppy i want to achieve this kind of stuff using material custom theme and available options without using extra classes

Comment: @WillHowell That is more generic document, no way to dive deep into theming or using real essence of material.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. That document should cover points 1-3 of your question. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @WillHowell May be i will put it this way... in custom theme which i am constructing, I want to give padding to md-toolbar and background color for md-table i am able to see classes for few components but i want to full list or major list

Comment: A full list of what? CSS class names?

Comment: @WillHowell yes

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material isn't a CSS framework like Materialize, Semantic UI, Bulma, etc. It is a collection of Angular components that are very prescriptive about how they look in order to match the Material Design spec. Because of this, it is also not well suited for "skins" like some other Angular frameworks.

At the moment, theming is limited to setting the primary, accent, and warning colors. You can read more about that [on the docs website](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). If you're interested in really overriding a lot of default styles, you should take a look at the [document](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) I mentioned in the comments, as it describes how to make sure your overrides will succeed.

Finally, if you're interested in understanding which classes and styles are applied to different components, you can look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/material2) or poke through the DOM with the inspector while debugging. Note that each component has two (maybe more) [stylesheets](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/chips). One is for positioning, and the other is for colors and typography. The latter will all be compiled into a "theme file" while the former will compile individually and load whenever the component loads at run-time.

Comment: yes, i understood the angular material intention, but when specifying $company-primary: mat-palette($company-blue,500,300,A700); i am always getting 500 which is default not able to use 300 or A700 which are lighter and darker version.so what is the use of defining those stuff?

Comment: you can access them still like `mat-color($company-blue, lighter)`

Comment: I can directly use it like mat-color($company-blue, 300) or like color: <some color> , i though that might be used in following way <button color="primary-lighter"> though it is not the working

Comment: Oh I see. They are prescriptive about it due to the spec and how much css it would cost to support every combination. Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6059).